# Convert pytorch float Sigmoid results to labels

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I am trying to make segmentation model using `Pytorch` and implement custom `IoULoss`:

```
def IoULoss(inputs, targets, smooth=1e-6):
    inputs = (inputs.view(inputs.size(0), -1) > 0.5)
    targets = targets.view(targets.size(0), -1)
    intersection = (inputs & targets).float().sum(1)
    union = (inputs | targets).float().sum(1)
    IoU = (intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth)
    return 1 - IoU.mean()
```

But when I train model, I am getting error:

`RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`

Is there any good way to cast my predictions to labels?

Full error traceback:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-3bfc1b43c8ba> in <module>()
----> 1 my_train(model, 30, torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01), IoULoss, train_loader)

2 frames
<ipython-input-41-ebe9c66b1806> in my_train(clf, epochs, optimizer, criterion, train_data, test_data)
     22             epoch_loss += loss.item()
     23 
---> 24             loss.backward()
     25             optimizer.step()
     26 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    253                 create_graph=create_graph,
    254                 inputs=inputs)
--> 255         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
    256 
    257     def register_hook(self, hook):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    147     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    148         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
--> 149         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    150 
    151 

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Model inference:

```
def my_train(clf, epochs, optimizer, criterion, train_data, test_data=None):

    cur_min_loss = 10e8
    train_losses = []

    for epoch_step in range(epochs):

        epoch_loss = 0.0

        for i, batch in enumerate(train_data):

            X, y = batch

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            prediction = clf(X)
            loss = criterion(prediction, y)
            epoch_loss += loss.item()

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            del prediction
            del X
            del y
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()

        train_losses.append(epoch_loss / (i + 1))
```

Criterion is `IoULoss`; `clf` final activation is `Sigmoid`; optimizer `Adam`, `train_data` - custom dataset inherited from `PyTorch Dataset`

Comment: post the full error traceback please

Comment: @ayandas added traceback

Comment: Can you show the code of your model inference?

Comment: @Ivan added inference

Answer (score 0):

The first expression in your loss function:

```
inputs.view(inputs.size(0), -1) > 0.5
```

is not a differentiable operator, hence the gradient cannot propagate through that operation.